# SQL Query Always getting '1' at the end Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have this code :

```
$mydata = DB::table('attendances')->where('date_only','=',$newdate)
                                  ->orderBy('logon','asc')
                                  ->count();
```

Yes, I get the count number, But it's output is wrong. I always get this `'1'` digit at the result, For example, If I have `7` records the Result will be `'71'` if I have `8` then `'81'`, `10` then `'101'`. And so on.

Comment: did you `print_r($mydata)` ?

Comment: yeah I did, what should i use?

Comment: try using `vardump($mydata )` or `echo $mydata->count`

Comment: Obviously you're doing something wrong. This one doesn't add any number to the result.

Comment: can everyone please read the manual on print_r

Answer (score 0):

Probably you output somewhere else `1`. You should try using it this way:

```
$mydata = DB::table('attendances')->where('date_only','=',$newdate)
                                  ->orderBy('logon','asc')
                                  ->count();
echo $mydata;
die();
```

And now check whether you get `1` at the end. Probably you won't so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using laravel Controller and I will output it to the Views

Comment: @jakebalba It doesn't matter. First check whether you get 1 at the end in above code or not when you put it in your controller

Comment: echo $mydata; is not working on views @marcinNabialek

Comment: @jakebalba Try it in your controller, not in view first

Answer (score 0):

Check the code where you are outputting the count. Do not get confuse with **'.'** and **'+'**